# Deploying openx into ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, openx, custom-routes

I'm trying to integrate `openx` into an `Ruby on Rails 2` application and I'm deploying my rails application on the root of my server like `'http://mydomain.com/'` so i put the `openx` folder in the **`public`** so it'd load in `'http://mydomain.com/openx/www/admin/'` hut i'm getting this error

```
No route matches "/openx/www/admin/"
```

Should i add a custom route on my `routes.rb` file?

Answer (score 2):

No matter what, I'd suggest setting up vhosts so that you can have oxadmin.mydomain.com go to /path/to/openx/www/admin and have oxdelivery.mydomain.com go to /path/to/openx/www/delivery and oximages.mydomain.com go to /path/to/openx/www/images

OX was designed so all files which should be public are in the 'www' folder - setting it up like above keeps only the www files publicly available while also separating your admin, delivery, and image domains